# Onsager on phase transitions

Tags: physics, theoretical-physics, quote, feynman

*Surely You're Joking Mr. Feynman* has Feynman ascribing to Onsager the following quote (during  the International Conference of Theoretical Physics in Kyoto, in 1953):

> "We should tell Feynman that nobody has ever figured out the order of
> any transition correctly from first principles."

Is there reason to believe/disbelieve Onsager said this? Was this true at the time? When did someone first correctly show the order of a phase transition from first principles? (I realize "show" probably has in this case multiple interpretations corresponding to different levels of rigour required I would leave this open to those answering.)

Comment: Is there a date or a period for that quote?

Comment: From https://www.aip.org/history-programs/niels-bohr-library/oral-histories/5020-4 I think it was during the 1953 meeting in Japan.

Comment: The [exchange](https://kiranazalea.blogspot.com/p/would-you-solve-dirac-equation.html?m=1) happened at the International Conference of Theoretical Physics in Kyoto, 1953, where Feynman was presenting his [Atomic Theory of Liquid Helium Near Absolute Zero](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.91.1301). What Onsager said was true at the time and may still be true if one really wants it "from first principles". Microscopic reductions of macroscopic behavior are notoriously intractable.

Comment: @Conifold This is as good as an answer...

Comment: "Microscopic reductions of macroscopic behavior are notoriously intractable" : this may be true (I don't know enough physics) but this was done for superconductivity (with a Nobel prize); see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCS_theory .  @Conifold

Answer (score 0):

First, the source linked by @Kvothe in a comment provides a wording that is (significantly) different from that in the OP.

Second, I can only guess what Onsager meant, but possibly that was about there being no good theoretical description of phase transitions in **three-dimensional** models based on calculations using, say, the canonical ensemble. Since 1953, there has been tremendous progress. @MikhailKatz mentioned BCS theory of conductivity; the renormalization group and $\epsilon$-expansion methods were developed. I don't work in this area anymore, but I believe there are now excellent expansions for critical indices. Onsager himself obtained an analytical solution for the phase transition in the **two-dimensional** Ising model in 1944.